# Unable to upload Images to sql server via pyodbc

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, image, uploading

I'm trying to upload an image to SQL server in Linux (raspbian) environment using python language.So far i was able connect to Sql server and also i created a table and i'm using pyodbc.

```
#! /user/bin/env python
import pyodbc 
from PIL import Image

dsn = 'nicedcn'
user = myid
password = mypass
database = myDB

con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, user, password, database)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

string = "CREATE TABLE Database2([image name] varchar(20), [image] image)"
cursor.execute(string)
cnxn.commit()
```

This part complied without any error.That means i have successfully created a table right? Or is there any issue?

I try to upload image as this way.

```
image12= Image.open('new1.jpg')
cursor.execute("insert into Database1([image name], [image]) values (?,?)", 
'new1', image12)
cnxn.commit()
```

I get the error on this part. and it pyodbc.ProgrammingError:

> ('Invalid Parameter type. param-index=1 param-type=instance', 'HY105')

Please tell me another way or proper way to upload a image via pyodbc to a database